# '__u32 __fswab32(__u32)' cannot appear in a constant-expression in netinet/tcp_md5.h

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, zeromq

In one of my code, I was facing below error because I was using <linux/tcp.h>.

========== Error ========

```
/auto/andpkg/rep_cache//wr-x86-xeon/5.0/sysroot/intel_xeon_32_core-wrs-linux/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:72:17: error: '__u32 __fswab32(__u32)' cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

=========================

So I changed to netinet/tcp.h and the error was resolved. However the next header file is netinet/tcp_md5.h and I found that netinet/tcp_md5.h in turn includes <linux/tcp.h>. So now I am getting the same compilation error and some redeclaration error.

========= Redeclaration error ===============

In file included from ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/netinet/tcp_md5.h:59:0,
                 from ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/src/options.hpp:38,
                 from ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/src/ctx.cpp:30: ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:91:0: error: "TCP_NODELAY" redefined [-Werror] ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/netinet/tcp.h:148:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:92:0: error: "TCP_MAXSEG" redefined [-Werror] ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/netinet/tcp.h:149:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:94:0: error: "TCP_KEEPIDLE" redefined [-Werror] ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/netinet/tcp.h:158:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:95:0: error: "TCP_KEEPINTVL" redefined [-Werror] ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/netinet/tcp.h:159:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:96:0: error: "TCP_KEEPCNT" redefined [-Werror] ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/netinet/tcp.h:157:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition

> ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:24:8: error: redefinition of 'struct tcphdr'
>   ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/netinet/tcp.h:67:8:
>   error: previous definition of 'struct tcphdr'

========================

========== Constant expression error again ==========

> ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:72:17:
>   error: '__u32 __fswab32(__u32)' cannot appear in a constant-expression
>   ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:72:17:
>   error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
>   ../../../../zeromq/conf.x86it/../zeromq-4.0.1/../../../../routing-sw/include/pre-os/x86it/os/linux/tcp.h:73:17:
>   error: '__u32 __fswab32(__u32)' cannot appear in a constant-expression

=============

Looks like there is a cross dependency. Has anybody faced this issue? What is the way to fix this issue?

Comment: Q: What are you trying to do?  build zeromq from source?  If so, are you cross-compiling for a different platform than your development workstation?

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes, you are right. My workstation is centos x86_64 and I am compiling for windriver linux. Toolchain is /auto/andpkg/rep_cache//wr-x86-xeon/5.0/sysroot/intel_xeon_32_core-wrs-linux.

Comment: @FoggyDay After adding -std=c++0x in c++ config flags, compilation went through fine.

Comment: Beautiful - thank you for following up.  Please "accept" your answer - it sounds like it will be useful to others, too  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding **`-std=c++0x`** in `CXXFLAGS`, compilation went through fine :

```
CXXFLAGS = -Wall           \
           -pipe            \
           -g                \
           -O2                \
           -fno-crossjumping   \
           -fno-strict-aliasing \
           -march=pentiumpro     \
           --sysroot=/auto/andpkg/rep_cache//wr-x86-xeon/5.0/sysroot/intel_xeon_32_core-wrs-linux \
           -m32                    \
           -Wno-variadic-macros     \
           -std=c++0x
```